# How do I style html nicely?

Tags: html

I saw a few resources online and I am curious how do I style as nicely as this one.

Show.html is the main page
emp.html will only be shown when one selects "Add New Record"

this is the page where one can add new employees

[image]

This is the page where it will show the details of the employees in a table format

[image]

Comment: Can u should research any framework for css,html. Ex: bootstrap

Comment: Please refer to [MDN on CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS).

Comment: Any kind souls can help me to style them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) could be enough to style like that

Comment: By adding the bootstrap is helps